# Not triggered OnActivityResult in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have *X, Z activities and Y class*. Y is view of activity X and called activity for result from X to Z..its not going to `onActivityResult` in X.

```
Activity X:

 SetContentView(Y);
```

and

```
Intent i=new Intent(x.this,z.class);
startActivityforResult(i,100);
```

---

`onActivityResult` method:

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==100)
    {
    Log.e("Message from Z","Message");
    }
    }
```

Activity Z:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, (new Intent()).setAction("close"));
            this.finish();
```

How to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new intent; you dont need to do that.

This should work:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);

finish();
```

---

Also as a recommendation dont use hard coded request code ( in your case 100). Declare a `private static final int` variable and use it when starting the activity for result (`startActivityforResult`) and when accepting the result on `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: @sreekanth please post the onActivityResult code of class X

Comment: well your code seems fine if you correctly take the above correction it should work for you; may be the problem is the way you are debugging can you put a break point inside the `onActivityResult` method instead of logging

Comment: yes tried with debug but not going into onActivityResult()

Comment: Did you put the break point out side of the if condition? put the break point out side of the if condition because the result from Z activity may not be RESULT_OK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91717/discussion-between-sreekanth-and-degen-sharew).

Answer (score 0):

Use setResult() like this:

```
Intent i = getIntent(); //gets the intent that called this intent
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
```

Add your intent as one parameter of setResult()

Comment: Did u add intent as parameter of setResult()?

Comment: Yes like..setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

in `onActivityResult()` update the code

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==100)
    {
      if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       Log.e("Message from Z","Message");
      }
    }
}
```

Activity Z:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: update your question with the whole code you are currently executing